# Flask Post is not coming to the Same Page

Tags: python, flask

I made a simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form to Post</title>
        <form action="post">
            <input type="text" name="theinput"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <p>{{theout}}</p>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

All I want t do here s input somethign in the boix and post it right underneath. This is the flask code I am using:

from flask import render_template, request

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def homepage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
       return render_template("index.html", theout=theinput)
    else:
       return render_template("index.html")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

What am I doing wrong here? (The HTML IS index.html)

Comment: Your code should in the `<body>` tag, not the head https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

Comment: I changed that but the issue still arises. I can't post to the same page via flask.

Comment: Where does `theinput` comes from ? Please explain better your problem, it's hard to understand "is not coming"

Comment: "theinput" is coming from th text box on the page. All I am trying to do is after you submit it, you can see it just below on the same page.

Comment: When you post here please, share code that works, here `theinput` would be undefined in the python code, you need to post a minimal but also working example ;) just one line is need to create theinput so let it

Comment: azro - I am just trying to get it to work. It should be simpler than this. I should be able to post input I put in via flask, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you look at the answers ? Could your edit your post with the form into the body, and the python code to read theinput, please

Answer (score 2):

The `action` attribute should be the URL you want to POST to, while the `method` attribute should be the method you want to use. So in your case, it would be:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
```

In flask, you need to make sure you get all the form fields through the `requests` module. After importing it, get the form field data by:

```
theinput = request.form['theinput']
```

Comment: I added that, but theinput is still not posting to the page.

Comment: @EClipse, I edited the answer to fix another issue in your code. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<form action="/" method="POST>.....</form>` ,  not `action="post"`

Action corresponds to the destination route for the desired HTTP Request.